Arranging value of boxplot in ascending order for a specific treatment (ggplot)
I would like to arrange my boxplot based on ascending values of a specific treatment. At the moment, they are dispayed alphabetically.
How could I modify my code to have them in ascending order and based on one of the two treatmetns (for example VIP)?
This is an example of my data set in excel (edit: restructured for easy R importing):
Peso <- structure(list(Accession = c("Potato", "Potato", "Potato", "Potato", 
"Potato", "Potato"), Genotype = c("#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", 
"#6"), Code = c("aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af"), Nome = c("L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L"), Data = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), Treatment = c("VIP", "VIP", "VIP", "MOCK", "MOCK", "MOCK"), 
    Weight = c(1.9, 1.46, 1.52, 1.29, 1.05, 1.52)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

This is my code:
Population <- ggplot(data = na.omit(Peso), aes(x = Code, y = Weight, fill = Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot( alpha=0.2) + 
  xlab("Genotype") + 
  geom_point()+
  ylim(0, 3.00)

Population + ggtitle("21dpi Dry-Weight") +
  ylab("Weight (g)") +
  xlab("Genotype") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", size = 15)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", 14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", 14)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, size = 9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#33FF00", "#000000"))


Welcome to stack overflow - please don't post code or data as images, it breaks screen readers and cannot be copy/pasted by people helping you.  Generally, using dput(head(Peso)) should give you something that can be pasted into your original question.

Hi, thanks, I have tried to arrange my question. Hopefully, now would be better.

The order of the categories in the X axis are alphabetic unless specified otherwise.
We can do that by making Code an ordered factor, based on first of all the Treatment and secondly the Weight.
Test data
Peso <- tibble::tribble(~Accession, ~Genotype, ~Code, ~Nome, ~Data, ~Treatment, ~Weight,
                      "Potato", "#1", "aa", "L", "A", "VIP", 1.90,
                      "Potato", "#2", "ab", "L", "A", "VIP", 1.46,
                      "Potato", "#3", "ac", "L", "A", "VIP", 1.52,
                      "Potato", "#4", "ad", "L", "A", "MOCK", 1.29,
                      "Potato", "#5", "ae", "L", "A", "MOCK", 1.05,
                      "Potato", "#6", "af", "L", "A", "MOCK", 1.52)

Set the factor with ordered levels:
Peso$Code <- factor(Peso$Code, levels = unique(Peso$Code[order(Peso$Treatment, Peso$Weight, Peso$Code)]), ordered = TRUE)

Then your plot:
Population <- ggplot(data = na.omit(Peso), aes(x = Code, y = Weight, fill = Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot( alpha=0.2) + 
  xlab("Genotype") + 
  geom_point()+
  ylim(0, 3.00)

Population + ggtitle("21dpi Dry-Weight") +
  ylab("Weight (g)") +
  xlab("Genotype") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", size = 15)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", 14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, color = "black", 14)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, size = 9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#33FF00", "#000000"))


